# Calling javascript inside option tag

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ToWord(index) {
    var theword = "";

    if (index== 0) theword = "Scheduled";
    if (index== 1) theword = "Ongoing";
    if (index== 2) theword = "Cancelled";
    if (index== 3) theword = "Finished";

    return theword;
}
</script>


<c:forEach var="statusItem" items="${statusList}">
    <option value = ${statusItem} <c:if test='${statusItem eq jobItem.getJobItem().getStatus()}' >selected</c:if>/>ToWord(${statusItem})</option>              
</c:forEach>


statusList.add("0");
statusList.add("1");
statusList.add("2");
statusList.add("3");
request.setAttribute("statusList", statusList);
```

Hello again... I am trying to convert an integer value into its word equivalent by using
a javascript function, but its not working. Tried searching the net but can find anything of help... maybe I just don't know what term to use.. I even don't know how to title my question.

Insted of showing "scheduled", "ongoing", on the combobox it is showing "ToWord(${statusItem})" literally.

I am using jsp jstl.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a script tag around the script, and you need a `document.write` call to put the result in the page:

```
<script>document.write(ToWord(${statusItem}))</script>
```

In the tag:

```
<option value = ${statusItem} <c:if test='${statusItem eq jobItem.getJobItem().getStatus()}' >selected</c:if>/><script>document.write(ToWord(${statusItem}))</script></option>
```